# Facebook Graph API Photo Upload: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

(Not sure which Stack site to post this on. Please point me in the right direction)

I've been experiencing an issue while uploading photos to Facebook Graph API where I receive an error:

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

or

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I believe this is an issue with the Graph API itself and not something that's being triggered from my end. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? What details can I provide so we can have a meaningful conversation about this issue?

The application is built in C# 4.0 and functions a large social media management tool. Photo posting is a small but important feature, so the increase in error rates is alarming.

We've had a Facebook/GraphAPI integration for a few years supporting image upload, photo posting, etc. This particular error has came up in the past, but I was unable to find a suitable solution to it. There is automatic re-attempt logic for re-attempting the API call, but it is disabled when photo uploads are involved. (We've seen too many instances where Graph API returns an error but actually uploads the image, resulting in re-attempts from our end and multiple images uploaded).

Facebook bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/438368212913456

Comment: Can you post some code showing what your're doing when the error occurs?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post exact code, it's complicated/lengthy and proprietary. The actual implementation is a multipart form upload, based upon this http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c